# Access url index instead of /home wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I would like to ask on how I can access my wordpress website index(homepage) without the /home in the url because currently I can access my website index when add the /home in the url.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please go to your **admin panel** 
then

Open : **Settings -> Reading**
 and set a Front page displays to A static page (select below) 
and select you page from "**Front page**" drop down

and then **save changes**

this may be help you

Comment: Does not solve my problem it redirects me to localhost{wordpress_folder}

Comment: you done any type of customization ??
else it work fine for us.

Comment: I have not done any customization :(. By the way my homepage is in my index.php file with a template name of Home

Comment: page you want to display in main page is available in front page drop down?

Comment: set your permalink setting to "Post name" if this may be work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127895/discussion-between-ronak-patel-and-sydney-loteria).

Answer (score 0):

```
www.example.com/home to www.example.com
```

It has two method to do this:

```
Method 1:
>> Login to you admin section area
>> select the Settings -> Reading
>> choose the static page radio box and then select you page which you want to display as a home page in your case it is /home
```

=======

```
Method 2:
>> Login to you admin section area
>> select the appearance =>Customize
>> select the Static Front Page and after this you need to to choose A Static page under the Front Page Display and choose you page form the select box.
```

Hope so this will work for you :)

Comment: I try to put my wordpress project in the root directory and perfectly works fine. The problem only occur when I put the wordpress in my subdirectory folder

Comment: You just need to add the url rewrite rules